# Check if item exists in specific <td> by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have items names in drop down and a quantity text box. i am adding item and its quantity to table  if quantity is greater then zero,
Now i want to check if item is already present in the table then just sum the quantity

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#addBtn").click(function(){

           var rmnameList = document.getElementById("rname");
           var name = rmnameList.options[rmnameList.selectedIndex].text;           
           var qty = $('#qty').val();

           if (qty > 0)
           {
                var tbody = $('#rTable').children('tbody');

                var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#rTable');
                //Add row
                table.append('<tr><td>'+ name + '</td><td>'+ qty +'</td></tr>');
            }


        });

   });
    </script>
```

[image]

I am unable to find the respective `<td>` element to update.

My jquery selector is :

```
$('#rTable tbody tr td:first-child')
```

and it returns:

```
[<td>​BUN​</td>​, <td>​Ketchup​</td>​, <td>​Banana​</td>​]
```

Comment: How are you accessing the `td`? What is your jquery selector?

Comment: @Shaharyar  $('#rTable tbody tr td:first-child')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an attribute on the `tr` to store the rname, and then use it to check whether the element exists

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    var name = $('#rname option:selected').text();
    var qty = $('#qty').val();

    if (qty > 0) {
      var tbody = $('#rTable').children('tbody');

      var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#rTable');
      //Add row
      var $tr = table.find('tr[data-rname="' + name + '"]');
      if ($tr.length) {
        $tr.find('td:last-child').text(function(i, t) {
          return +t + +qty;
        })
      } else {
        table.append($('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + qty + '</td></tr>').attr('data-rname', name));
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="rname">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<input id="qty" />
<button id="addBtn">Add</button>
<br />
<table id="rTable"></table>
```

Comment: It works for me, but what does this line do `return +t + +qty;`

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq that adds the existing value of the `td` and current qty.... the `+t` and `+qty` is used to convert the string values to numeric one's

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter`

```
var target = table.find("tr").filter(function(idx, tr) {
  var td = tr.find('td:first-child');
  return (td.text() === name);
});

if (target.length > 0) {
  // Sum up
} else {
  // Create new
}
```

I'd suggest you  use `<tr data-name="' + name + '"><td>'+ name + '</td><td>'+ qty +'</td></tr>` to create a `tr` with `data-name`

Then the filter can be simplified to:

```
var target = table.find("tr").filter('[data-name="' + name + '"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` to check it the item is already present on the table.

```
var count = $('#rTable td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim() == name;
    });
```

count will be greater that one if the table contains that element.

Also you can use `$("#rname option:selected").text();` inorder to get the selected option text.

```
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
    var name = $("#rname option:selected").text();
    var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val());
    var count = $('#rTable td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim() == name;
    });
    if (qty > 0 && count == 0) {
        var tbody = $('#rTable').children('tbody');
        var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#rTable');
        //Add row
        table.append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + qty + '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```